# Multiplle Threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a loop for example `for (int i=1;i<=10;i++)` and I want to create 10 threads inside it, each one to perform the same task on a set of data and return the result. Then process this result inside the loop. Any ideas how this can be done?

```
for (int i=1;i<=10;i++) {
    Work w = new Work();
    Thread t = new Thread(w);
    w.getResultFromThread();
    //process w
}

class Work implements Runnable {
     public void run() {
      //perform tasks
     }

     public int getResultFromThread() {
          return result;
     }
}
```

I want each thread to work in parallel but when I recieve the result to be one by one.

Comment: Read up on executors; that's exactly what you want here.

Comment: Thread won't return anything, but an Executor can return something back to calling thread. So use an executor. 1) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html  2) http://www.javaworld.com/article/2078809/java-concurrency/java-101-the-next-generation-java-concurrency-without-the-pain-part-1.html

Comment: There seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding of parallel here. How can you *not* process the results one-by-one when the processing is being done in a for-loop?

Comment: @CaptainMan I have tried the code above and the threads don't finish one after each other.

Comment: @GeR what do you mean by "I want each thread to work in parallel but when **I recieve the result to be one by one**" if you "have tried the code above and the threads ***don't* finish one after each other**"?

Comment: my question might be confused. I have a dataset. I want to create 10 threads that work on this dataset, each thread returns a value. I want to retrieve this value and use it for another operations. So I should retrieve 10 values, since I have 10 threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not wish to use executors, the you can do it in the following way:

```
int size = 10;
Thread[] threads = new Thread[size];
Work[] works = new Work[size];
for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {

    Work w = new Work();
    works[i - 1] = w;
    Thread t = new Thread(w);
    threads[i - 1] = t;

    // Start the thread
    t.start();
}
// now you have started all the threads


for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

    // wait for each thread to complete execution, before extracting the result
    // [here i am assuming that getResultFromThread() does not block
    // till we get the result, if it blocks, then no need to join]
    threads[i].join();

    int result = works[i].getResultFromThread();
    // do something with the result
}
```

Comment: Why do I get this error on the line `int result = threads[i].getResultFromThread()`  `the method getResultFromThread is undefined for the type Thread`

Comment: Sorry about that, answer is fixed. The reason for that error: The thread is the container for the runnable, and the thread does not have the method getResultFromThread, that method is present in the Work object.

Comment: Idiomatic Java would be to have the for loop be `for (int i=0; i<size; i++)`,  and then you don't need the `[i-1]` in the array indices, just use `[i]`.

Comment: @user949300 it is based on the example provided in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Work> listOfJobs = new ArrayList<Work>();
ArrayList<Thread> threadList = new ArrayList<Thread>();
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++) {
  Work w = new Work();
  listOfJobs.add(w);
  Thread t = new Thread(w);
  threadList.add(t);
  t.start();
}

for(Thread t : listOfJobs) {
    t.join();
    w.getResultsFromThread();
}
```

This way you don't need executors for whatever reason you might have not to use them.

First, you create all the threads and start them(1st loop), then you call `join` on them, to make sure thread you want to get results from is done(2nd loop).

You can always pass your `listOfJobs` to some other method to process your results.

Comment: I don't think `w.join()` will work (ha ha) since `Work` implements `Runnable`, not `Thread`.

Comment: @user949300 yep, thank you for pointing this one out. There's something in writing code straight into answer that makes me unconscious.